# Combobox Data Binding (independent choice)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

i bind some data at two different combobox like this:

```
BindingList<Customer> customers = new BindingList<Customer>();
customer.Add(new Customer(1, "Mike"));
customer.Add(new Customer(2, "Max"));
customer.Add(new Customer(3, "Taylor"));

combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox1.DataSource = customers;

combobox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox2.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox2.DataSource = customers;
```

It's working good, but if i selecting some item in combobox1 this item automatically select in combobox2. How to resolve this problem (need independent choice) ?

Comment: Has my solution worked for you?

Comment: Not quite, copy it's create a new object, but my BindingList having more then 100 rows.

Comment: But my solution is the only one which  is working. Even the answers in the duplicate are quite similar to mine.... If it helped you anyway,, can you please mark it as solevd? Thanjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code **does** work seamlessly for me:

```
BindingList<Customer> customer = new BindingList<Customer>();
customer.Add(new Customer(1, "Mike"));
customer.Add(new Customer(2, "Max"));
customer.Add(new Customer(3, "Taylor"));

BindingList<Customer> customer2 = new BindingList<Customer>(customer);

combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox1.DataSource = customer;

combobox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox2.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox2.DataSource = customer2;
```

Comment: customers2 = customers --> is the same instance. Isn't it?
My advice to create a new instance by passing a list of items into constructor or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, same effect.

Comment: @deeperzone I've seen there is a `CopyTo` extension method so please try this one,, I'll add it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @deeperzone now fixed, works fine for me. Tested it also!!